# Match dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to custom match 2 dataframes(different from joins, I think). I want to get df3 from df1 and df2. Here's the sample code --

```
df1=data.frame(c1=c(1,1),c2=c(1,0),c3=c(0,0),c4=c(0,1))
> df1
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  1
> df2=data.frame(c2=c(6,8),c3=c(4,5),c5=c(1,2))
> df2
    c2 c3 c5
  1  6  4 1
  2  8  5 2
> df3=data.frame(c1=c(NA,NA),c2=c(6,8),c3=c(4,5),c4=c(NA,NA))
> df3
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1 NA  6  4 NA
2 NA  8  5 NA
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why are you only choosing the second set when the column names match?  Some explanation of how to get to `df3` would be good.

Comment: Maybe `merge(df1, df2, all.y = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @RichardScriven - Sorry if I was not clear. I basically want to put df2 in df1 format. df1 is my model training set and df2 is my test set. I wanna use predict() on the df2 but the columns should be in the same order and same in number..

Comment: This sounds like RandomForest. If so, you should subset larger data set into training and test sets as even columns must be consistent in the model.

Answer (score 0):

First merge the data, keeping all rows from `df2`

```
df3 = merge(df1, df2, all.y = TRUE)
```

Then re-order the columns so that only the columns from df1 are present and they are in the same order:

```
(df3 = df3[names(df1)])
#   c1 c2 c3 c4
# 1 NA  6  4 NA
# 2 NA  8  5 NA
```

Note that this assumes that if there are matches, you want to pull the values from the extra `df1` columns. That is, if `df1` had a row where `c2 == 6` and `c3 == 4`, then that row's values for `c4` and `c1` would end up in `df3` instead of `NA`.